How can I batch cut hundreds of videos at exactly 20:44?
I am currently 'cutting' many videos, all in the same folder, one video at a time. I am using Kdenlive.
I would like to know the best and most efficient way of 'cutting' all those videos at the 20:44 timestamp automatically, using Ubuntu 22.04.
To be completely clear: I need to ensure that each video ends at the current 20:44 timestamp, leaving only videos that run from 0:00 to 20:44.

Try the following:
for f in *.mp4 ; do ffmpeg -i $f -t 00:20:44 -c copy $(basename $f .mp4)-cut.mp4 ; done

This loops over all *.mp4 files in the current directory, assigning each filename to $f variable, and then calls the ffmpeg command with input file $f and output file $(basename $f .mp4)-cut.mp4. As for the last construct, $(command) represents output of command. The command basename $f .mp4 outputs the filename with the .mp4 ending removed, so $(basename $f .mp4) represents just this, then the part -cut.mp4 is added onto it.
This assumes your filenames do not contain spaces. If your filenames do contain spaces (which is a bad idea anyway; you should never use spaces in filenames, as space is meant to separate filenames and not be a part of them), you should use a slightly modified version of the command:
for f in *.mp4 ; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -t 00:20:44 -c copy "$(basename "$f" .mp4)-cut.mp4" ; done


Unrecognized option 'cut.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Did you type it exactly as here? Because I just tested it and it works for me. You must enter the directory with the video files first of course!

There is no space between ) and -cut - probably that's the mistake you made. If there's no space in the command, you should not type it, because spaces are important.

I didn't make any "mistakes".
I copy-pasted it.
for f in *.mp4 ; do ffmpeg -i $f -t 00:20:44 -c copy $(basename $f .mp4)-cut.mp4 ; done
What do you mean "enter the directory"? I entered the directory  and opened a terminal window:
nunovski2001@nunovski2001-MS-7A34:~/Downloads/Dragon Ball_trim$
Then I inserted your command and clicked Enter

Do your filenames contain spaces? If yes, you must first get rid of all spaces from filenames. Using spaces in filenames is a fundamentally bad idea anyway.

It's not a "specific command". In any Linux command spaces are meant to separate the filenames, not to be a part of them. Therefore no reasonable Linux user would ever think of using spaces in filenames. If you really want to use spaces in filenames, you can, but then you have to use some tricks in the commands, like in my edited answer.

@raj The output naming that you have used could be neater (although this is a bash thing). Instead of "$(basename "$f" .mp4)-cut.mp4"  try "${$f%.mp4}-cut.mp4".
